# Problemas al llamar a una función a través de include

Tags: c, gcc

Estoy aprendiendo C a través de y aplicándolo a los microcontroladores de la serie avr sobre linux.

Estoy batallando para poder tener una consola por usb-serie.

Tengo un pequeño código en un archivo llamado pruebas_uart.c y un include llamado manejo_uart.c y manejo_uart.h

El fallo que me da es el siguiente:

"2: undefined reference to `uart_iniciacion'"

El código principal es:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#define UART_BAUD  57600

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "manejo_uart.h"

#include "librerias/Arduino_Nano_Cabeceras.h"






int main(void) {


    Arduino_Nano_Set_Led_Out();
    Arduino_Nano_Led_L_Set_On;
    
    uart_iniciacion();

    

    
    printf("Pruebas de comunicaciones desde arduino Nano con atmega328p\n");
    
    int n;
    printf("Introduce un numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("El valor es %d.\n", n);

    if ( n== 1972)
    {
        
        printf("OK\n");
  
        printf("Bienvenido al sistema.\n");
  
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Lo siento, no tienes acceso.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El include, manejo_uart.h, es este:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void uart_iniciacion( void);

void uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream);

char uart_getchar(FILE *stream);
```

Y por último el manejo_uart.c, es este otro:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

#include "manejo_uart.h"

void uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream);
char uart_getchar(FILE *stream);

FILE uart_output = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
FILE uart_input = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(NULL, uart_getchar, _FDEV_SETUP_READ);
FILE uart_io = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, uart_getchar, _FDEV_SETUP_RW);

stdout = &uart_output;
stdin  = &uart_input;
    

void uart_iniciacion(void) // Para atmega328p
{
  #if F_CPU < 2000000UL && defined(U2X)
    UCSRA = _BV(U2X);             /* improve baud rate error by using 2x clk */
    UBRR0L = (F_CPU / (8UL * UART_BAUD)) - 1;
  #else
    UBRR0L = (F_CPU / (16UL * UART_BAUD)) - 1;
  #endif
    UCSR0B = _BV(TXEN0) | _BV(RXEN0); /* tx/rx enable */
}

void uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream) {
    if (c == '\n') {
        uart_putchar('\r', stream);
    }
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    UDR0 = c;
}

char uart_getchar(FILE *stream) {
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, RXC0); /* Wait until data exists. */
    return UDR0;
}
```

Si meto todo en un solo archivo funciona bien, pero al separarlo y meterlo a través de include me salta el error indicado.

Agradezco vuestra ayuda, gracias!!.